# How to set border to ExcelPicture Box

Tags: c#

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pImagePath);
            OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture excelImage = null;
            if (image != null)
            {
                excelImage = excelWorksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Name", image);
                excelImage.From.Column = 0; 
                excelImage.From.Row = 6; 
                excelImage.SetSize(230, 168);

                excelImage.From.ColumnOff = 19050;
                excelImage.From.RowOff = 19050;
                image.Dispose();
            }
```

It Will show complete Image in `ExcelPicture`. But i have to set Border Around the `ExcelPicture`.

Comment: WPF? Winforms? Something different? The easiest would be probably just wrapping the ExcelImage in a `Border`control.

Comment: i already tried the Border Control but it also not work ....